# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value SwiftUI AnimatedImage

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` to display images from a firestore database and currently getting the error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Not quite certain how to do the if check to prevent the force unwrapping so would appreciate if anyone can show me an alternate syntax example.

```
@ObservedObject var movies = getMoviesData()

...

ForEach(self.movies.datas) { item in
        VStack {
             Button(action: {}) {
                 AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: item.img)!)
                  .resizable()
                  .frame(height: 425)
                  .padding(.bottom,15)
                  .cornerRadius(5)                           
              }
         }
}
```

Also tried comparing to nil (as suggested in the article: [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)) but not working.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: @pawello2222 Not quite. It says that "the simplest way to check whether an optional contains a value, is to compare it to nil." I'm trying to do that but it's giving conflicting errors. I understand I need a check to make sure the variable has a value, but would appreciate if you or anyone else can give a syntax example pertaining to my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're comparing an *unwrapped* value with `nil`. Your program crashes even before the comparison.

You need to compare an optional value instead:

```
if (URL(string: item.img) != nil) { ... }
```

Better even to use `if-let` to make sure that `url` is not `nil`:

```
Button(action: {}) {
    if let url = URL(string: item.img) {
        AnimatedImage(url: url)
            .resizable()
            .frame(height: 425)
            .padding(.bottom, 15)
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I just needed an example to understand how to implement that. Many thanks, Sir!